# How do we use a LINQ query on a Dictionary with a nested object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

What I am ultimately trying to do is bulk insert the values from a dictionary into the database.

Here is how my dictionary is setup:

```
    public class Record
    {
        public int ValueNumber;
        public string ValueString;
        public byte[] ValueBinary;
        public DateTime ValueDateTime;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Record> Elements = new Dictionary<string, Record>();
```

I want to ultimately, do this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = Elements.AsEnumerable();           

// Create a table from the query.
DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

// Insert into database
SqlBulkUtilities.BulkInsertDataTable(ConnectionString, "Orders", dt);
```

Here is what my SqlBulkUtilities looks like:

```
public class SqlBulkUtilities
{
    public static void BulkInsertDataTable(string connectionString, string tableName, DataTable table)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                new SqlBulkCopy
                (
                connection,
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                null
                );

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            connection.Open();

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What each DataRow in the DataTable should look like is this:

key, ValueNumber, ValueString, ValueBinary, ValueDateTime

Where "key" is the key in each entry in the Dictionary.

If "key" were right in the "Record" object, then I would have no issue, I expect.  But it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
var Result = from e in Elements 
             select new 
             { 
                 Key = e.Key, 
                 ValNum = e.Value.ValueNumber... 
             };
```